# More advanced Task manager for Ubuntu/Linux with GPU support and more info

Tags: 18.04, monitoring, system-monitor

I have been using Linux and Ubuntu for a long time, and recently completely switched to Ubuntu. I liked the amount of features the Windows 10 Task Manager provides, and I am wondering if there is a task manager for Ubuntu which also has the features Windows Task Manager has. Currently, I use gnome-system-monitor, but it is missing some features. So I am looking for a Task Manager for Ubuntu/Linux which has these features:

1. Basic task managing like any other Task Manager, e.g. being able to kill processes
2. The ability to view CPU, Memory, Disk and GPU usage.
3. The ability to view memory usage on the GPU and which part of the GPU is being used would also be VERY handy/required.
4. The ability to have each CPU thread be a separate graph, this is really needed for me.
5. The ability to view information about system components, e.g. the speed of the RAM, the type of CPU and GPU, The current frequency of the CPU and possibly GPU.
   I know this is a lot to ask, but does such thing exist for Ubuntu?(It is something I really miss in Ubuntu, and pretty much all those features are needed for me, without having to open 4 separate programs)

Thanks!

Edit:
It needs to be one with a GUI, preferably a decent looking one.

Comment: If you have an NVidia graphics card you may try `sudo apt install nvtop` (it's a commandline tool anyway).